# An unhandled exception breaks the application?

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

It is said in .net 4.0, an unhandled exception in task will make the application broken when it is finalized. (It is also said in .net 4.5, MS edits the exception rule that unhandled exception won't be thrown).

But I tried below code, to see the appliction. (in .net4.0), but it seems strong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { throw new Exception("xxxxxx"); return 1; }
            , CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The code run the GC.Collect() to finalize the Task object, but the application is ok. It isn't broken.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you're running it on .NET 4.0, or did you just compile targeting 4.0?

Comment: My target framework .Net Framework 4. And use `clrver`.Versions installed on the machine:
v1.1.4322
v2.0.50727
v4.0.30319

Comment: Try adding a `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` handler and see if it gets called.

Comment: TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException will handle the exception, it proved that the GC reclaim the task object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have .net 4.5 installed on your machine, that does an in place modification of .net 4.0 as well which may be why you are getting the behavior you are seeing.

If you want unobserved exceptions to still be thrown you can add the following section to your config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

[More info about `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346(v=vs.110).aspx)